# C# class belong to xaml file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm not familiar with wpf or C# language, but I want to generate xaml code and it's cs code from a conceptual language model (DSL), I wrote a lot of templates to generate xaml tags and cs codes and binding them to my data model using MVVM.
for example my template to create cs class for my xaml file is :

```
namespace $domain
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for $name.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class $name : Window
    {
        public $name()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

and my question is:
is this part of code enough to generate a cs class for my xaml file? and where is the InitializeComponent method?

and this is my xaml template

```
<Window x:Class="$domain.$name"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:$dmdomain"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="$title" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:$dataModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    $content
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, the class inherits `Window`.

You might want to check this out: http://en.csharp-online.net/XAML%E2%80%94Code-Behind_Class

excerpt:

> The InitializeComponent() method isn’t visible in your source code
>   because it’s generated when you compile your application. Essentially,
>   all InitializeComponent() does is call the LoadComponent() method of
>   the System.Windows.Application class. The LoadComponent() method
>   extracts the BAML (the compiled XAML) from your assembly and uses it
>   to build your user interface. As it parses the BAML, it creates each
>   control, sets its properties, and attaches any event handlers.

Comment: thanks for your answer, and is this part of cs code enough for my xaml file?

Comment: In essence. As you develop the XAML the components you add should also appear.

Comment: so how it detects and finds my components to init them? how it works?

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio - it usually does it automatically. But you can add them by hand as well. See the previously referenced article for more detail.

Comment: No , my problem is that I'm a linux user and I'm using monodevelop to write cs codes